# Tab order problems with RadioButton-based component

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I've got a problem with following example code in flex:

Test.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:local="*">
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:TextInput id="text1"/>
        <local:TestComponent id="tc1" />
        <local:TestComponent id="tc2" />
        <local:TestComponent id="tc3" />
        <s:TextInput id="text2"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

TestComponent.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:RadioButtonGroup id="grp"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:RadioButton id="redRadio" groupName="grp"/>
    <s:RadioButton id="yellowRadio" groupName="grp"/>
    <s:RadioButton id="greenRadio" groupName="grp"/>    
</s:Group>
```

When I start the application and press Tab to cycle through controls, the focus jumps to the first text box, then to the first radio button of the first TestComponent, and then directly to the last textbox missing the second and the third TestComponents.
This behavior seems wrong to me. Can anyone help me to fix this?

UPD: Explicitely setting tabIndex does not work either:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:local="*">
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:TextInput id="text1" tabIndex="1"/>
        <local:TestComponent id="tc1" tabIndex="2"/>
        <local:TestComponent id="tc2" tabIndex="3"/>
        <local:TestComponent id="tc3" tabIndex="4"/>
        <s:TextInput id="text2" tabIndex="5"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and debugging into the Flex source i found the solution.
My mistake was, that i assumed, that attributes group and groupName must correspond to the same RadioButtonGroup control. But they don't have to!
The group attribute can point to the real RadioButtonGroup control and for the groupName (which is used by the FocusManager to find out, if a RadioButton belongs to a group) we can use some randomly generated name. 
So, the working code looks like this:

TestComponent.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
         initialize="init()">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function init():void {
                var groupName:String = Math.random().toString();
                redRadio.groupName = groupName;
                yellowRadio.groupName = groupName;
                greenRadio.groupName = groupName;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:RadioButtonGroup id="grp"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:RadioButton id="redRadio" group="{grp}"/>
    <s:RadioButton id="yellowRadio" group="{grp}"/>
    <s:RadioButton id="greenRadio" group="{grp}"/>  
</s:Group>
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to radio buttons, it seems that Flex does not set the focus on individual radio buttons, but rather on radio buttons groups. You navigate between radio buttons using the left/right or up/down keys. This makes sense for radio buttons, because tab-key navigation is unidirectional.

What I did, using your example, was create a new component, **TestComponent2.mxml** and change the radio group id:

```
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">

    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout />
    </s:layout>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:RadioButtonGroup id="grp2" />
    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:RadioButton id="redRadio" groupName="grp2" />
    <s:RadioButton id="yellowRadio" groupName="grp2" />
    <s:RadioButton id="greenRadio" groupName="grp2" />
</s:Group>
```

Also, I replaced the 7th line, in your **Test.mxml** file, like this:

```
<local:TestComponent2 id="tc2" />
```

This way it worked correctly. Using the tab key, the focus is cycled this way:

1. The first text input
2. The first radio button group (left/right key navigation)
3. The second radio button group (same here)
4. The second text input

So it seems you need to assign different names to the radio button groups.

Hope this helps, have a great day!

Comment: Thank you very much, but this does not solve my problem :( I wanted to place such components in a loop based on input data and i cannot create separate component for every possible case...

Comment: It does, if you use different group names. You cannot use the same name for multiple radio button groups.

Comment: Hmmm, how can i create a component, which uses different group id each time it is used?

Comment: You can create a custom skinnable component, with a required skin RadioButtonGroup part, then in the initialization stage you set as the part's ID a random number, or the current timestamp.

Comment: How can one change some element's ID?

Comment: I don't think you can change it, you can just set it when you create a component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tabIndex` property to manually set control for tab button.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it. The tab order stays the same. Updated the question post.